# Android best practice for a communication between views and a central model

Tags: java, android

Im creating an native android app which has 4 views and 4 textviews. Each view and textview are connected, beacuse each textview is actually within the view.

Here is a sketch of the layout:

[image: Android Layout]

I want to have a central model class to hold values and then the views and textviews should show the models values realtime.

Values should be able to change in the model when changing either a view or a textview or something else internal changes the model, it should also show in the views and textviews.

So how is the best pattern to do this? Is it somehing a pub sub, were values can be send from a view to the model, react on it and then from the model to the views and then react on it visually?

My first try is making the model static so it can remember values but I really feel the architecture is bad. Any ideas?

Comment: [architecture components](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/arch/)

Comment: You could use Databinding https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your problem... but maybe creating a custom view to warp your View and TextView and a ViewModel with the values that you want to keep.
Your ViewModel could expose LivteData to your custom view and your custom view can observe this changes and update the values.
Check out these links, maybe it can help you 
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel